# How to query from SQL comparing with array members?

Tags: c#, sql, arrays

So I have an array containing computer names called `hostnames[]`.

Contains: `compname1, compname2, compname3` etc.

Actually it gets it's members from another SQL query.

I have a data table and I need to query all rows where hostname column has any of the computer names in my array.

something like:

```
select * from table where hostname in hostnames[]
```

How should I proceed to achieve my goal?

EDIT:
I was thinking on the below:

```
string temp = "'" + hostnames[0] + "'";
for(int i=1; i<hostnames[].Lenght; i++)
{
temp = temp + ",'" + hostnames[i] + "'";
}
string query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE hostname IN (" + temp + ")";
```

Comment: Can we see the code you've tried?

Comment: Here's an article for you: [Parameterize a query containing an IN clause](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/5819/parameterize-a-query-containing-an-in-clause.aspx)

Comment: Based on your tags, I'm not sure if you're doing this in C# or T-SQL. Can you clarify, please?

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer now, but If you are using SQL-Server 2008 or later **PLEASE USE [TABLE VALUED PARAMETERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)**. It is so much cleaner on the SQL side rather than using `LIKE` on a delimited string as is usually suggested.

Comment: @GarethD - Cool. I've never even heard of table valued parameters before - that's going to have a pretty profound effect on my coding technique going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to use parameters for an IN clause is to use [Table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx), in your case you will need a type as a table with one nvarchar column. I've used a generic name so the type can be reused without confusion:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.StringList AS TABLE (value NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

Then it is simply a case of adding your values to a DataTable and passing this as a parameter to your select command:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(string)));

for (int i = 0; i < hostnames.Length; i++)
{
    var dr = dataTable.NewRow();
    dr[0] = "";
    dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
}
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE HostName IN (SELECT Value FROM @StringList)", connection))
{
    SqlParameter stringListParameter = new SqlParameter("@StringList", SqlDbType.Structured);
    stringListParameter.Value = dataTable;
    stringListParameter.TypeName = "dbo.StringList";
    command.Parameters.Add(stringListParameter);

    // OPEN CONNECTION EXECUTE COMMAND ETC

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 ways to achieve what you want. You choose what works best for you.

1. Use IN as in your code
2. Break down to OR. A IN (1, 2, 3) => A=1 OR A=2 OR A=3
3. Use Table Valued Parameters
4. User the sql query passed earlier. ex: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE hostname IN (Select hostname from tableusedEarlier)"